# how to get seconds on org-clock measurements?

Tags: org-mode

With `C-c C-x C-i` and `C-c C-x C-o` we can get measurements on how much time we spend on tasks:

```
:LOGBOOK:
CLOCK: [2016-11-21 Mon 22:50]--[2016-11-21 Mon 22:57] =>  0:07
CLOCK: [2016-11-21 Mon 22:30]--[2016-11-21 Mon 22:30] =>  0:00
:END:
```

But the smallest unit is a minute. How can we get measurements in seconds?

Comment: May I ask, why is your interest in seconds? Because tasks are seldom tracked to the seconds resolution

Comment: @Prasanna Actually, JIRA does allow doing that.

Comment: @Prasana, yes. It is for presentation tracking. sometimes you have only 15 minutes to present a talk and in those cases it is interesting to track to the second level. I split the presentation points into individual org-bullets and track that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might consider using `org-timer` instead. For example, you can use `M-x org-timer-item RET` to start a bulleted list with a timestamp, and `M-RET` to create new timestamped items afterwards. `M-x org-timer RET` (`C-c C-x .`) inserts a relative time with seconds.

Comment: I didn't know this feature.  Thanks!  It might be better, for SO answer, to clearly state that the current org-mode does not support second in `org-clock`.

Comment: @Sacha Chua, thank you. If I understand correctly, `C-c C-x .` inserts a timestamp text in whatever bullet point is in, right? after that, you create bullets as you normally would, and then you can `C-c C-x .` again on selected bullets that you want to relative imestamp. right? Initially I thought that by just hitting M-RET I would get a new bullet already with a timestamp on, but that is not the case. Or is it? (maybe I'm doing something wrong)

Comment: I see now, so `C-c C-x -` inserts a `-` item and `M-RET` inserts another `-` item but with the timestamp already inserted for you. Thank you Sacha, that should seal the deal.